# Convergence in Probability of Positive Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, self-learning

We have to show that for a positive sequence of random variables $X_n \geq 0$ and a random variable $X$ s.th. $X_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow}X$ it follows that $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 0) = 1$. Additionally, let $\mathbb{P}(E) = 0$ be the set with probability of zero.

Here is my argument (i have the feeling it's not correct):

$$
X_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow}X := lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) = 0, \text{ for } \epsilon > 0.
$$

This implies that there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N$:

$$
\{|X_n - X| > \epsilon\} = E
$$

otherwise $\mathbb{P}(\{|X_n - X| > \epsilon\}) > 0$. Or considering the compliment:
there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N$:

$$
\{|X_n - X| \leq \epsilon\} = E^c
$$

thus in the set with positive probability. Thus we can rewrite the equation:

\begin{align*}
|X_n - X| \leq \epsilon &\Leftrightarrow -\epsilon \leq X_n - X \leq \epsilon \\
&\Leftrightarrow -\epsilon - X_n \leq  - X \leq \epsilon - X_n \\
&\Leftrightarrow \epsilon + X_n \geq  X \geq X_n - \epsilon \\
\end{align*}

Thus $X \geq X_n - \epsilon > 0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X \geq 0) = 1$, because $X_n \geq 0$.

Is that a correct argument? I have the feeling that I used an argument for almost sure convergence.

Comment: It's not clear what is the first $E$. Moreover, the $E$ you defined by $\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon \}$ depend on $n$ (so, it would be better to write it as $E_n$). And I don't understand why the fact that $X_n\to X$ in probability implies that there is $N$ s.t. $\{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon \}=E$ for all $n\geq N$...

Comment: Just to conclude, what you have done at the end is good but not so well written. You have that $|X_n-X|<\varepsilon \implies X>X_n-\varepsilon >-\varepsilon $, therefore $\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\mathbb P\{|X_n-X|\leq \varepsilon \}\leq \mathbb P\{X>-\varepsilon \}$. Since for all $\varepsilon >0$, $$\mathbb P\{|X_n-X|\leq \varepsilon \}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }1,$$  you get that $\mathbb P\{X>-\varepsilon \}=1$ for all $\varepsilon >0$, and thus $\mathbb P\{X\geq 0\}=1$ as wished.

Comment: Much appreciated! Can you post this as an answer? I'd like to vote this answer as the solution.

Comment: If $X_n \to X$ in probability, then $X_{n_k} \to X$ almost surely for some subsequence. The result follows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also show that $P(X<0)=0$ to arrive at the conclusion. Let $\eta,\varepsilon>0$. Then
$$\begin{aligned}\{X<-\eta\}&=(\{X<-\eta\}\cap \{X_n>\varepsilon\})\cup(\{X<-\eta\}\cap \{X_n\leq \varepsilon\})\subset\\
&\subset \{|X-X_n|>\varepsilon\}\cup\{|X_n-X| \geq \eta\}\end{aligned}$$
and
$$P(X<-\eta)\leq P(|X-X_n|>\varepsilon)+P(|X_n-X| \geq \eta)\to 0$$
and finally
$$P(X<-\eta)=0,\,\forall \eta\implies P(X<0)=0$$

Comment: Very nice! Much appreciated.